# PHP parsing error causes connection reset

Tags: php, apache, error-reporting

I have been coding on the same system for a couple years, but recently I had missed a close bracket } and instead of a descriptive error, the browser gave me a "connection reset" error.

This is on localhost (windows vista, PHP Version 5.2.5, apache2.2) I have display_errors on, development environment, the Php.ini file is error report `E_ALL & E_STRICT & E_NOTICE`.  These have not changed since this problem has occurred..

Stranger still, I have a simple phpinfo() file written, and when I hit it in firefox, it displays, and then at the end the connection is reset.  with chrome, seems to work.

I'm baffled, but just noticed that when I get the phpinfo page displayed, error_reporting is 0 when in the php.ini file, `error_reporting=E_ALL & E_STRICT & E_NOTICE`.  there is nothing else that should be overriding this.

Update:  I am finding that even simple errors (referencing a value that doesn't exists, with E_STRICT on) will cause the connection reset problem.

Update 2: I know most people will think this question has been answered 100 times, this is different.

2 files:

```
ini_set('display_errors','On');
ini_set('display_startup_errors','On');
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
include("file2.php");
```

file2.php:
has a parse error

```
if(isset($x){echo "HI";}
```

On my development server - Connection Reset (error 500)
on my production server - displays parse error.

Comment: You mind showing the code and/or the error logs.

Comment: Can you include the logs from apache `error.log` fiile aswell?

Comment: the error log is not showing anything, code is above.  Looking into how to force apache to write to the error log to make sure I am looking at the write error log.  Thanks Darren

Answer (score 0):

I ended up re-installing Apache and PHP and this resolved the issue, however, I had made no changes to php5apache.dll or the config file when this started happening.  If anyone else has seen this, I'd be interested to see if you have any thoughts on what might have happened.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing exactly the same problem today, having upgraded to PHP 5.5 and keeping my Apache at 2.2. It took me multiple installs to get the PHP working as expected, so I am reluctant to reinstall.

Error logs:

```
[Wed Jul 30 09:44:32 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'require' (T_REQUIRE) in C:\\Apache2.2\\htdocs\\laravel\\site\\public_html\\index.php on line 22
[Wed Jul 30 09:44:32 2014] [notice] Parent: child process exited with status 255 -- Restarting.
[Wed Jul 30 09:44:33 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Win32) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Jul 30 09:44:33 2014] [notice] Server built: Mar  4 2010 11:27:46
[Wed Jul 30 09:44:33 2014] [notice] Parent: Created child process 9992
[Wed Jul 30 09:44:33 2014] [notice] Child 9992: Child process is running
[Wed Jul 30 09:44:33 2014] [notice] Child 9992: Acquired the start mutex.
[Wed Jul 30 09:44:33 2014] [notice] Child 9992: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Wed Jul 30 09:44:33 2014] [notice] Child 9992: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
```

Comment: I have just updated to Apache 2.4 and I am experiencing the same problem. I am not seeing any difference between Firefox and other browsers. Seems server-side to me.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing a similar issue (error reporting not displaying on a production environment) Also in the same situation where the server has been a development environment for the better part of a year, I had reinstalled both apache and php, but also did a bootscan before reinstalling, found a babylon rootkit.